# Datatype of encrypted password

Tags: asp.net

I want to encrypt my password and store to my DB, SQL Server 2008 R2.
For that I took the password from text box and encrypted using proper function and want to store in back end.

Tell me which datatype I have to use for encrypted password column.

Comment: Varchar(). btw, you might want to read this : http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: An encrypted string is still a string.  Store it like any other string.  Also, don't *encrypt* passwords, *hash* them.  There's a significant difference.

Answer (score -1):

Namespace:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
```

Encrypt Function:

```
public static string Encrypt(string Message)
        {

            string Password = Message;
            byte[] Results;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Password));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
            TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                HashProvider.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Results);
        }
```

Decrypt Function:

```
public static string Decrypt(string Message)
        {
            string Password = Message;
            byte[] Results;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Password));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
            TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
                Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                HashProvider.Clear();
            }
            return UTF8.GetString(Results);
        }
```

**How to use??**

For Encrypt:

```
string encryptpassword=Encrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim());
```

For Decrypt:

```
string decryptpassword=Decrypt(txtPassword.Text.Trim());
```

*NOTE : txtPassword is a textbox where you can enter a password*

Comment: How does this answer the question "What datatype should I use?"?